# Insertion sort algorithm doesn't bother about last number in list

Tags: python, algorithm

I'd like to write a insertion sort algorithm. I've almost finished it, but the function itself seems to not even bothering about last number. What could be wrong here?

```
def insertion_sort(user_list):
    sorted_list = []
    sorted_list.append(user_list[0])
    for index in range(0, len(user_list)):
        if user_list[index] < user_list[-1]:
            for reversed_index in range(index, 0, -1):
                if user_list[reversed_index] < user_list[reversed_index-1]:
                    user_list[reversed_index], user_list[reversed_index-1] = user_list[reversed_index-1], user_list[reversed_index]
                    print(user_list)

    print("\n\n", user_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_list = [4, 3, 2, 10, 12, 1, 5, 6]
    insertion_sort(user_list)
```

Comment: Why are you comparing with `user_list[-1]`?

Comment: I've tried to do something similar like here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/ (just without looking at the solution code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `if user_list[index] < user_list[-1]` with `if user_list[index] < user_list[index-1]`.

While doing insertion sort, we compare two consecutive elements to check if they are out of order. Comparing with the last element of user_list seems like a typo.

Comment: What a goofy mistake... Thank you!